# Set Magento block template in layout xml

Tags: magento

Having trouble setting a block template in Magento's layout xml. I'm attempting to set the template of a child block, not the entire page layout (almost all docs out there explain how to set template of the layout).

Background: I'm *updating* a layout handle in my custom action, using the `<update />` tag in my module's layout xml.

Essentially, I want to reuse the layout and blocks of the built in product view action, but provide custom templates for a few blocks. (Not just overrides, these need to be brand new templates that are only triggered on my custom action and are themselves overrideable).

My layout html:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<mymodule_product_index>
    <update handle="catalog_product_view" />
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" 
        name="product.info" output="toHtml" template="mymodule/product.phtml" />
        </reference>

    <reference name="product.info.bundle">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>mymodule/customtemplate.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</mymodule_product_index>
</layout>
```

The `setTemplate` on `product.info.bundle` never works; it doesn't seem to affect layout at all. I've tried wrapping the `<reference>` in other `<reference>` nodes from parent blocks with no effect. Is it possible to replace block templates in this way? I feel that my problem stems from the fact I'm using an `<update />`.

By the way, I know my layout xml is being loaded and there are no errors, the rest of the file is working fine, caching is disabled, have cleared cache anyway, etc.

Comment: Do you know what means/doing update tag? The update tag, taking update handle which is <catalog_product_view> and merge it's contain with the current layout.xml

Comment: Check this link [Magento Layout XML's](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)

Comment: @OğuzÇelikdemir Yes that is why I'm using the `<update />` tag; I wish to take an existing layout and reuse it. I've used the page you referenced quite extensively; it's a great resource...though the only `setTemplate` examples change out the layout, not a block template.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your approach is almost correct.
Two things:
**1. Set a new template instead of instantiating a new block**
Instead of just assigning a different template to the `product.info` block, you are creating a new instance with the same name, replacing the original instance, and then the new template is set on that. Instead use this:

```
<mymodule_product_index>
    <update handle="catalog_product_view" />
    <reference name="product.info">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/product.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</mymodule_product_index>
```

That should take care of the product view template in a clean way.

**2. Handle processing order**
If you look at where the view block `product.info.bundle` for the bundled products is declared, you will see it happens in the bundle.xml file, in a layout update handle called `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>`.

Your code is referencing the block from the `<[route]_[controller]_[action]>` layout handle, i.e. `<mymodule_product_index>`.

The thing to be aware of here is the **processing order** of layout handles.
Roughly it is:

1. `<default>`
2. `<[route]_[controller]_[action]>`
3. `<custom_handles>`

The `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>` handle belongs to the third type of layout handles, which means it is processed after the `<mymodule_product_index>` handle.
In essence, you are referencing the block `product.info.bundle` before it has been declared.

To fix this you will need to use the `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>` handle as well. Of course this will effect every bundled product display. Using layout XML only there is no clean way around that.

Here are a few suggestions how to solve that problem.

You could create a separate route in your module to show the bundled products, and then include the `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>` handle using an `update` directive for that page, too.

In your custom action controller, you could add another layout update handle that is processed **after** `<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>`.

You could use an event observer to set the template on the `product.info.bundle` block if it is instantiated. One possibility would be the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`.

You get the idea, there are many ways to work around this, but they require PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, it was very helpful. I got it working using your event observer approach.