# Magento get all product details which is display in homepage

Tags: magento, product

How to programmatically in a model get all product details which is currently display in Homepage magento.

Comment: It ultimately depends which products are shown on your homepage. It could be new arrivals / featured products / or just based on your custom attribute value

Comment: yes thats true, and i would like to find a way to get all these product details programatically in a model. or i have a product's id, let say id '1234', i would like to know if this product is display in the homepage. thanks for you help..

Comment: Hello check this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543732/set-magento-block-template-in-layout-xml

Comment: Hello MagikVishal, the link does not help. any other ideas.. thanks