# Magento header module not showing properly

Tags: php, xml, magento

I created a new layout and assign it to my home page.The layout working fine,Here is my local.xml file.

```
 <page_home_layout translate="label">
    <label> Layout Home Page</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/home.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>Home Page</name></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="header">
       <block type="youama_slider/slider" name="youamaslider" template="youama/slider/slider.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
   </reference>
</page_home_layout>
```

**My problem is**
The module youamaslider is not showing in header,It is showing after the footer.Is there anything wrong i have done?

Comment: edit the template, not the layout. - possible dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9543732/367456

Comment: @hakre That is not actually my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<reference name="header">
<block type="youama_slider/slider" name="youamaslider" template="youama/slider/slider.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
</reference>
```

by:

```
<reference name="header">
<block type="page/html_header" name="youamaslider" template="youama/slider/slider.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: This is not working for me,actually youama_slider is a slider extension